# How to track the progress of HttpClient post

Tags: c#, android, http-post, asp.net-web-api2, httpclient

I'm building an Android app that sends binary data to the server using HttpClient PostAsJsonAsync method. Is is possible to track the progress of the data being sent?

I'm using the code below to send the data to the server:

```
                    var client = new HttpClient();

                client.BaseAddress = uri;

                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
                        new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/bson"));

                var result = client.PostAsJsonAsync(uri, fileBytes);
```

Answer (score 0):

Implement your http post using an AsyncTask. By using this task you can track the progress of the task.

Comment: something like having the code inside an async method and having the return value set to something? what will I be returning? Can you give a an example?